# How to open documents that contain certain characters through WebDav?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, webdav

I use ActiveXObjects to edit documents through WebDav using an online service according to:

```
function openWithWebDAVCallback(data, xmlObj)
{
    var document = new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.2");
    var documentPath = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName('davUrl')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    document.EditDocument(documentPath);
}
```

However sometimes `documentPath` will contain a number sign (#) which results in `EditDocument` crashing and not allowing access to the document. I've tried replacing the number sign with `"& # 3 5 ;"` without success.

How can I allow special characters like #, ?, = etc. to be used in document names and still allow the user to access them through WebDav?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `#` means "Start the fragment identifier" in a URL.

You need to encode it for URLs, not for HTML.

In JavaScript: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)